# glassfish and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, glassfish-3

i saw that my glassfish server has a number of updates available, and i`ve noticed that hibernate 3.5 was one among them. I was wondering why would glassfish use hibernate. Then i have searched a little and i found that glassfish's default persistence implementention is toplink, and some guys tried to switch to hibernate.
But again, why ?
Is there a way of remove hibernate jar's from my app and put them on the application server so that every app that runs on glassfish can use them. I already use connection pool managed by glassfish and here i can understand the advantages.
Can someone explain or point me somewhere where i can find some documentation about that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://javafromthetrenches.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/using-hibernate-jpa-with-glassfish/), the default persistence provider of glassfish is toplink which now became eclipselink.  So, I am not sure about the updates you mentioned.  May be hibernate was added to the AS.

If you would like to use the jar but have it commonly stored in a repository, may be Maven would be a better choice.  This is because, when you have the jar in the AS and not in your development environment, both development and unit testing would become difficult.